# Server requirements ffmpeg for insert text a small video

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, server, hardware

I will use ffmpeg to write a username and add a picture to a 30 second video. 618 users will benefit from this service per day. How do you think a server needs? Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62661337/edit) your post to make it clearer?

Comment: that's a pretty small requirement. if you don't already have an environment you can run it in, I'd suggest a small DigitalOcean droplet rather than standing up a full machine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to your requiremens:

```
OS    : CentOS 7 (or any other linux)
HDD   : 1TB (If SSD it's much better)
RAM   : 16GB
CORE  : 4Core - 6 Core
```